# When does Chewbacca die?

Tags: star-wars

On Wookieepedia it says that Chewbacca dies in 25 ABY, can anyone confirm this? I am concerned about the next movie and I do not want to be disappointed.

Comment: Nothing post-Episode VI is set in stone. It's all [Legends](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page) for now. We don't know what happens to Chewie.

Comment: The book in which Chewbacca died is no longer canon. Hence, within Disney's new standard, he is still alive.

Comment: Give it the right shave and a haircut, and any Wookie could be Chewie.

Comment: @MarkEdward I am so glad for this.  Chewbacca was my favorite charachter and while I had enjoyed a lot of RASalvatores books, I never forgave him for killing off Chewbacca (and then someone replaced him with that cat creature).

Comment: Not that it makes his death better, but Salvatore was forced by executives to kill Chewbacca as a sales move. Salvatore simply chose to give Chewbacca the most epic death he could think of: growling defiantly while being crushed by an entire moon.

Comment: Wookieepedia is wrong. He is still alive. He will be in upcoming Star Wars movie.

Comment: @CodeWarrior agreed. At least the cat guy didn't last long. And Leia/Han seemed to work well once they got used to it.

Comment: @omegacron what cat guy?

Answer (score 8):

He will, at the least, [return for the next movie](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-episode-7-chewbacca-peter-mayhew/).

> THR is reporting that Peter Mayhew is also returning as the 7’5” (or so) tall Chewbacca, the seasoned wookiee warrior and companion to former smuggler-turned rebel hero Han Solo (Ford) from the original Star Wars trilogy. There should be more official confirmation on that front, as production on Episode VII has already partially begun.
>
> There was previously some back and forth, on the matter of whether Mayhew would be physically able to reprise his iconic role in the next Star Wars installment. Shortly after rumors emerged asserting that he might be replaced in the Chewbacca role (which he reprised in Episode III), Mayhew passed on a message to fans, claiming “I intend to pursue the role of Chewbacca for Episode VII,” having undergone double-knee replacement surgery in order to regain his ability to walk. Then, about a week ago, news emerged that Mayhew won’t be attending the 2014 Comicpalooza Con, which takes place at the time as Episode VII will be shooting – and thus, breathed new life into rumors about his involvement with the film.

Also, as Doc stated below, he does show up in the second teaser trailer for Episode VII.

Since the film has been said to take place over 30 years after *Return of the Jedi*, our furry friend definitely lives longer than in the novels.

Comment: Chewbacca also appears in the [most recent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngElkyQ6Rhs) (second) teaser trailer for Episode VII (Star Wars: The Force Awakens).

Comment: @Doc:
I thought he did, but I wasn't in a position to check at the time.

Comment: A small point, but do we know that the sequence with Chewie isn't a flashback?

Comment: @Richard:
That's true. :-P Even Mayhew's stated involvement might be a prelude to him being killed off before the events. But, at that point, we'd might as well posit that any footage might just be the dream of one of the characters, so we can't really know anything.

Comment: I met Peter Mayhew a couple of times at cons. That guy has several issues, and I don't mean his knees. I'm pretty sure he was stoned out of his mind one of those times.

Comment: @Omegacron: Although, admittedly, painkiller medication for the knees might account for some of that. One of my friends from college had knee problems, something where the cartilage degraded over time, leaving bone on bone, and she was on some pretty powerful pain medications.

Comment: @SeanDuggan : It's possible. He seemed a lot more lucid on the other occasion, but he was rude & irritable both times. Maybe he's just not much for cons, I dunno. It was a stark contrast to other celebrities, though, who are generally cheerful and seem happy to be there, meet fans, etc.

Answer (score 6):

What you refer takes place in the Legends story arc *The New Jedi Order*, specifically in the first novel, *Vector Prime*. In it,

> An alien race known as the Yuuzhan Vong invades the known galaxy from outside the rim. On the planet of Sernpidal, Chewbacca is unable to board the Millennium Falcon in time after saving Anakin from being crushed. He defiantly embraces his death as a moon comes crashing into the planet, brought down by Yuuzhan Vong biotech. His death is a major plot point throughout the rest of the story arc and affects many of the other main characters.

As others have noted, this is not Disney canon, and in that arc, his fate remains to be decided.